# modify checkbox using javascript

Tags: javascript

I had declared 5 checkboxes with name and id attribute in a html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="One" id=11>One<br/> 
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="Two" id=12>Two<br/> 
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="Three" id=13>Three<br/> 
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="Four" id=14>Four<br/>
```

After declaration, I want to run a javascript that would enable the checkbox1 using that checkbox id.

Let me know to clarify something.

Comment: enable how? are they initially disabled?

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="category" value="One" id=11>One<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="Two" id=12>Two<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="Three" id=13>Three<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="Four" id=14>Four<br/>                                                  <script type="text/javascript">/*JS Code to enable the Checkbox 1*/ </script>

Comment: If you are generating the code on the server side (or even if it is static code), you know you can make a checkbox be ticked by default by adding `checked="checked"` as attribute?

Comment: I agree but I want to enable the checkbox after their declaration through javascript.

Comment: @ankitjava: So you are creating them with JS. You did not say that ;) (at least not that it was clear to me :D)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check/Uncheck checkbox with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206565/check-uncheck-checkbox-with-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this for checking the checkbox:

```
document.getElementById(<id of first checkbox>).checked = true;
```

Try this for enabling the checkbox:

```
document.getElementById(<id of first checkbox>).disabled = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
   document.myform.box1.checked = true;
```

or

```
document.getElementById('myid').checked = true;
```

see an full example : http://www.rgagnon.com/jsdetails/js-0007.html

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('checkbox1').checked = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

To check a check box you can use :

`document.getElementById("Checkbox_ID").checked = true;`

And to uncheck a check box you can use :

`document.getElementById("Checkbox_ID").checked = false;`

And for more info visit [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp) page