# Disable button if one field has input but not the other, enable when both have value (one is a select)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of fields that are required (not shown here) but then two that are optional. **However, if *either* of these two gets input, the other IS required.** So what I'm trying to accomplish is disabling the submit button as soon as one or the other has input, then re-enabling it once both have input. I ALSO need to re-enable if both clear back to empty.

I'm *almost* there it seems. One is a select, the other is a text input. I think one of my issues here is needing 'keyup' and 'onchange' in the same function (or maybe blur or something else entirely).

So here's my start. It may not be the right direction but it's half working, so hopefully this is an easy fix.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/internetjason/9ujqjvkm/)**

HTML

```
<div id="createnewtask">
     <h4>Create New Task</h4>

    <div>
        <label for="fassignedto" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Assign To</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="fassignedto" id="fassignedto">
            <option value="0">&nbsp;</option>
            <option value="12456">Chad</option>
            <option value="12430" selected="">Jason</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="ftasktypeid" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Task Type</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="ftasktypeid" id="ftasktypeid">
            <option value="0" selected>&nbsp;</option>
            <option value="6">Appointment</option>
            <option value="1">Call Back</option>
            <option value="5">Campaign</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="fduedate2">Due Date</label>
        <input type="text" name="fduedate2" id="fduedate2" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Date">
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="notesave" name="notesave" onclick="return fnsavenote();">Submit</button>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#createnewtask').keyup(function () {
    if ($('#ftasktypeid').val() != 0 && $('#fduedate2').val() != "") {
        $('#notesave').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else if ($('#ftasktypeid').val() == 0 && $('#fduedate2').val() == "") {
        $('#notesave').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#notesave').attr('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: If you can't set the due date until the select is chosen, just hide the due date until select is set and then make due date required

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`$('#notesave').attr('disabled', true)` and

`$('#notesave').removeAttr('disabled')`

Try

`$('#notesave').prop('disabled', true)` and

`$('#notesave').prop('disabled', false)`

The `disabled` HTML attribute is only used by the browser to determine the initial value when it renders the page. The `disabled` DOM property is what actually stores the value of whether or not the input is disabled.

[This works just like the `checked` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392450/bootstrap-checkbox-radio-buttons-do-not-change-input-value/18392577#18392577)

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. Like I said, I needed to do both keyup and change in the same function. I believe this 'bind' is working as desired. Please correct me if I'm wrong...

```
$('#createnewtask').bind('keyup change', function () {
    if ($('#ftasktypeid').val() != 0 && $('#fduedate2').val() != "") {
        $('#notesave').prop('disabled', false);
    } else if ($('#ftasktypeid').val() == 0 && $('#fduedate2').val() == "") {
        $('#notesave').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('#notesave').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

I also edited to 'prop' as per @tomaroo's advice. Thanks!

I updated the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/internetjason/9ujqjvkm/)**.