# bootstrap checkbox-x not updating DOM correctly when checked - how to validate form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I'm using [Kartik Visweswaran's bootstrap styled checkboxes](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-checkbox-x) because I need big easy boxes for tablet/phone users on my web app. Here's what a typical box looks like:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input id="check1"
            name="option1" 
            type="checkbox" 
            value="0"
            class="checkbox" 
            data-toggle="checkbox-x" 
            data-three-state="false" 
            data-size="lg">
    <label>$this->cut</label>
</div>
```

Note that the `input` tag is not nested between in the `label` tags (does this screw up screen readers? Is it a bug?). The checkbox-x doesn't toggle if you nest it. You can verify this behaviour by playing with the jsfiddle below.

I'm validating that at least one checkbox is checked with something like this:

```
function check_checkboxes(checkboxes) {
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
            alert("at least one checkbox is checked");
            return true;
        }
    }
    //if no checkboxes were checked, return false
    return false;
}
$("#submit_button").click( function(e){
    if(!(check_checkboxes($(".checkbox")))){
        //if no checkboxes are checked, warn
        alert("No checkboxes checked.");
});
```

I'm aware of the imput checked state vs DOM checked state issue [described in this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392450/bootstrap-checkbox-radio-buttons-do-not-change-input-value), but the jquery `.checked` method seems to be validating the checked status fine, as per [this fiddle that I created.](http://jsfiddle.net/3n53sdp0/3/) The DOM is updated to the OPPOSITE of the true checked state of the box (i.e. [here's a firebug screenshot of a box when it's checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApdOf.png)). Verify this yourself! This is a bug I guess?

So the question: how do I validate that at least one checkbox-x is checked with javascript in a way that doesn't have much frankencode which does the opposite of what it means? Or is there a better way to get big checkboxes (like jquery-ui)? I'm trying to avoid using form validation rules, because it doesn't quite suit the complex form and the presentation of warning alerts that I'm creating.

Answer (score 0):

Well after trying out a few other libraries, I like [checkBo](http://elmahdim.com/checkbo/). Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3n53sdp0/4/), and yes, it does update the DOM correctly.

HTML

```
<div>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <label class="cb-checkbox cb-md">
            <input id="check1" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="option1" value="0" />Option 1</label>
        <label class="cb-checkbox cb-md">
            <input id="check2" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="option2" value="0" />Option 2</label>
        <label class="cb-checkbox cb-md">
            <input id="check3" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="option3" value="0" />Option 3</label>
    </form>
</div>
<button id="submit_button" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

JS

```
$checkboxes = $("input.checkbox");
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").checkBo();
});

function check_checkboxes(checkboxes) {
    if (checkboxes !== null) {
        alert("checkboxes are not null, length = " + checkboxes.length);
    } else {
        alert("null checkbox list");
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
            //        if (checkboxes[i].is(":checked")) {
            alert("return true");
            return true;
        }
    }
    alert("return false");
    return false;
}

$("#submit_button").click(function (e) {
    if (!(check_checkboxes($checkboxes))) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("no checkboxes are checked");
    } else {
        alert("at least one checkbox is checked");
    }
});
```