# Wrong checkboxes being checked in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, checkbox, meteor-blaze

I have a bizarre issue with Meteor and likely Blaze as well.

I have a guest list with names displayed in a table. The first cell has a checkbox which sets the `arrived` flag on the record. The layout then filters the names so as not to display arrived guests.

For some reason, when checking a checkbox, it will perform the correct action on that record (change the flag and hide the row), but also leave the next name's checkbox checked without affecting that record at all.

Here's how it looks before I click the topmost record:
[image]

And after I click the topmost record:
[image]

Here's the relevant code:

*client/Names.js:*

```
Template.Names.helpers({
    names(){
        let listId = FlowRouter.getParam("listId");
        var list = Lists.findOne({_id: listId});
        return Lists.findOne({_id: listId}).names;
    }
});

Template.Names.events({ 
    names(){
        const instance = Template.instance();

        let listId = FlowRouter.getParam("listId");
        var filter = Session.get('filterQuery');
        var list = Lists.findOne({_id: listId});
        var showArrivedGuests = instance.state.get('showArrivedGuests');

        if(filter !== "" || !showArrivedGuests){            
            var pattern = stringToTerms(filter);
            var regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'i');

            // Filter results by search terms
            list.names = _.filter(list.names, function(name){
                if(!showArrivedGuests && name.arrived) return false;
                return (regex.test(name.firstName.tokenize()) || regex.test(name.lastName.tokenize()));
            });
        }

        let names = _.sortBy(list.names, Session.get('sortNames').term);
        return Session.get('sortNames').descending ? names : names.reverse();
    },
});
```

*Template:*

```
{{#each names}}
    <tr class="{{#if arrived}}arrivedChecked{{/if}}">
        <td class="arrived">
            <input type="checkbox" class="arrivedChecker" checked="{{arrived}}" id="name{{id}}" />
        </td>
        <td class="f_name">{{firstName}}</td>
        <td class="l_name">{{lastName}}</td>
        <td class="plus">{{plus}}</td>
        <td class="actions">
            <a class="delete alert"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

[Here's a link to the app if anyone would like to play around](https://batterylists.herokuapp.com/). I don't want to go through the trouble of removing user account verification, so you would have to make an account, make a list, then add names manually.

### EDIT:

In the template, `arrived` is a boolean value in each name object.

I stored each name in an array nested in the `Lists` object, which also means that I generate the `id` for names manually.

When I originally posted, I didn't want to make a gigantic post with all my code, so I just posted what I thought was relevant. I decided to put it on GitHub though, so [here's the link](https://github.com/aviemet/guestlists).

### EDIT 2:

I just noticed that my delete button is doing something similar, when it's clicked and a record is deleted, the following delete button stops working.

Checked in the inspector, it looks like the checkbox and the delete buttons aren't actually disappearing on re-render, even though the template should clearly be excluding them. They disappear when I check and uncheck the 'Show Arrived Guests' box, but not in reaction to user input for some reason.

Could it have something to do with attached events? Do event listeners continue to exist on these elements even after they've been re-rendered out of the page? If so, should I be listening to click events on the table and rely on bubbling to figure out the origin?

Comment: I did take a look but your app is in `--production`, too hard to debug.

Comment: We are missing code for checked event and arrived helper. Can you show that?

Comment: Don't have a pc here now but have you tried making a subtemplate of the html part within the each? This sometimes helps with rendering problems concerning each loops.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I moved that over which cleaned up the code a little, but unfortunately had no effect on the strange checkbox behavior.

Comment: if `id="name{{id}}"` and `{{id}}` returns undefined, you end up with the same ids  (i.e. `id="name")`, that would be why the false checkbox is updated, ids being unique. Are you sure it should not be `{{_id}}` instead?

Comment: I managed to get the expected behavior by changing my `id` variable inside the `names` array to `_id`, even though it's just a plain nested array and I'm generating the unique id manually. If anyone has a robust answer as to why this is the case and feels like sharing it, that'd be super cool.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the way you apply checked value.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="arrivedChecker" {{checkArrived}} id="name{{id}}" />
```

Helper:

```
checkArrived: function() {
   var check = this.arrived;
   return check ? "checked" : "";
}
```

Source: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18392577/5628454)

Comment: I broke that out but no change in behavior. Though I'm glad to have changed to what seems to be a best practice. I just noticed that my delete button has the same issue too. Clicking a delete button makes the one below stop working. It's almost like these elements aren't disappearing even though the re-render should eliminate them.