# Detect change event for radio inputs (with labels styled as buttons) in bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

As per the title, I'm trying to detect a change event (that doesn't seem to be occurring when I inspect the DOM) in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zav9brcs/). The radio inputs are styled using bootstrap classes. Why aren't I getting a change?

For reference, here's some code:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-sm btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="preview" id="preview-enabled" value="true" autocomplete="off" checked>Alice
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="preview" id="preview-disabled" value="false" autocomplete="off">Bob
  </label>
</div>
```

The input radios aren't changing when the buttons are clicked.

I'm also getting a weird error that jquery is required for bootstrap's js (however jquery is included before bootstrap's js as per [the official instructions](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "checked" attribute of the input `radio` element doesn't change (therefore not triggering the `eventListener`); it is the [underlying DOM property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18392577/3790954) `checked` of that element that changes.

You would think that the solution therefore would be to listen for changes to the DOM property on that node with a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). However [this doesn't work either](http://jsfiddle.net/6DHXs/1/), because it's not a change in the DOM, just a state change. And it seems (without using a shadow DOM framework like React) that there's no way to track this without polling.