# JavaScript check multiple checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

```
        <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="A">A</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="C">C</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="D">D</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="E">E</input>
```

I have value A and C, how to use javascript make A & C checked

Comment: You should have shown us what you've tried until now or you should just have checked the duplicates of that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206565/check-uncheck-checkbox-with-javascript to find a possible solution of that specific situation.

Comment: Also, note that `<input>` elements are void elements - that means that they don't have a closing tag. Use a `<label>` to associate text with an input, and you can make your elements self-closing by adding a slash: `<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="A" />`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you.

```js
var myNodeList = document.querySelectorAll("input[value=A], input[value=C]");
for (i = 0; i < myNodeList.length; i++) {
    myNodeList[i].checked = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="A">A</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="C">C</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="D">D</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="E">E</input>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
['A','C'].forEach(v=> document.querySelector(`[value=${v}]`).checked=1)
```

```js
['A','C'].forEach(v=> document.querySelector(`[value=${v}]`).checked=1)

// and her is longer but theoretically more efficient version:
// document.querySelectorAll(['A','C'].map(v=> `[value=${v}]`)+'').forEach(c=>c.checked=1)
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="A">A</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="C">C</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="D">D</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="E">E</input>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[value=A]")[0].checked = true;
document.querySelectorAll("input[value=C]")[0].checked = true;
```

Comment: Note that `document.querySelectorAll()` returns an array of nodes, so you'd have to access them via index (eg. `result[0]`). That's probably the reason your answer wasn't accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just give the checkbox an id like:

```
   <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="A" id="checkA">A</input>
```

then use the following javascript:

```
document.getElementById("checkA").checked = true;
```

Comment: I cant give each checkbox an ID because  I have may be ten checkboxes with same name[]

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign a id to the input box first then you can call javascript by using that id.

```
  <html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function setValue()
    {
       document.getElementById("A").checked = true;
       document.getElementById("C").checked = true;
    }
    </script>
    <body>
       <input id="A" type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="A">A</input>
       <input id="B" type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="C">C</input>
       <input id="C" type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="D">D</input>
       <input id="D" type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="E">E</input>
       <br/><br/>
       <button onClick="setValue()"> Set Value </button>
    </body>
  </html>
```