# Why i always fail to make check mark to checkbox via javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Look to my code below :

**HTML :**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="xyz[1][]" id="sel_44" style="margin:2px;" value="12345" onclick="myClick(this)">
```

**Javascript :**

```
<script>
$('#sel_44').attr("checked", true);
</script>
```

**I already try every method (method that suggest by acceptance answer) in this URL :** [Check/Uncheck checkbox with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206565/check-uncheck-checkbox-with-javascript)

> **My Problem and Question** :
>
> I can sure $('#sel_loc_cb_44') is not null
>   and not undefined. But i can make checkmark via javascript or jquery.
>   How to fix my code and what's the source of problem?

**Please kindly add jsfiddle to your solution post. thank you**

Comment: Set the `prop`, not the `attr`.

Comment: Michael i can see many answers are marked as useful anything worked out?

Comment: Make sure code runs after DOM is loaded. Wrap it in `ready`.

Comment: I will give accept answer if the solution working for me. However as i can say i sure the DOM is exist (not null and not undefined)

Comment: Looks like you need to add doument ready function https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/5935/

Answer (score 2):

try using

```
$('#sel_44').prop("checked", true);
```

you must change the propery of the DOM object instead of attribute

Comment: @Michael attr change attributes of an a lement not the properites of an element to change a property of an element  you must use prop function

Comment: It's not working for me. Can you give me example in jsfiddle?

Comment: You use button. How if i want to do it without press a button? cause i can't do it without use button

Comment: you mean in page load?

Comment: Like my code in the question. HTML is above and then i write JavaScript below the HTML to force check the checkbox. But i don't want to user HTML attribute like checked="checked".

Comment: try  to change the checked attribute after documetn loaded 
https://jsfiddle.net/1vwqe31s/4/

Answer (score 1):

Since jquery 1.6+ `prop` method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while `attr` retrieves attributes. Here `checked` is a property. So use [**prop**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for checking a checkbox.

```
$('#sel_44').prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this with jquery:

```
$("#sel_44").prop('checked',true);
```

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol ok it writing mistake i edited it thank u

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#sel_44').attr("checked", true);
});
```

I have tried in the jsfiddler, looks like you need to put your code inside the document ready function.

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/5935/

Comment: I don't want to do that when clicked. I want to checked when the first time it showed but using Javascript not write the DOM checked="checked"

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
  $('#sel_44').prop('checked',true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="xyz[1][]" id="sel_44" style="margin:2px;" value="12345">
```

Comment: I don't want to do that when clicked. I want to checked when the first time it showed but using Javascript not write the DOM checked="checked"