# Changing an HTML checkbox

Tags: html

How can I change an html checkbox dynamically using JavaScript?

I need a checkbox to be updated (ie ticked) after a key press.

```
<label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox" id = "record">
<div class="slider round">
</div>
```

Update: this is what I was looking for:

```
document.getElementById('record').checked = true;
```

Comment: Do you mean changing its appearance when checked?

Comment: I mean being able to set it to "checked" remotely, so the appearance changes when I press a key.

Comment: You would need to write some Javascript to do it. What part do you not know how to do, reacting to a keypress or changing the checkbox status? Have you followed the instructions/documentation/tutorials you find when you google those tasks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check/Uncheck checkbox with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206565/check-uncheck-checkbox-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ELEMENT.checked = true` or `false` to set its check status.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    // assuming desired key is "enter". You can change it to whatever key you prefer.
    if (e.which == 13){
        document.getElementById('record').checked = true;
    }
});
```