# Automatically check a particular check box on a webpage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to automatically check a particular "check box" on a webpage, there are 100's of them with multiple options. I need to check one from all?

[image: Example]

In the picture, I need to select all the "approved" check boxes.

Comment: provide code instead of image?

Comment: add `checked` to checkbox,

Comment: Can you please share the code, to make it easier to understand? Making it simple you should add `name` attribute to the group of radios and `checked` attribute to check the one you want.

Comment: In your script `$('input[type="checkbox"]').find("input[name="Approved"]").attr('checked',"checked");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check/Uncheck checkbox with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206565/check-uncheck-checkbox-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this answer: [Check/Uncheck checkbox with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206565/check-uncheck-checkbox-with-javascript)

Using the built in console of google chrome you can select the wanted checkboxes on classname or id and then check/uncheck them as wanted.

Answer (score -1):

on that specific checkbox you can set as type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked

them this will be auto checked when opens that page

Thanks

Comment: boy this answer is going to be down voted. like a lot. To prevent this 1.read the question properly and wirte better answers or 2. You can use a picture of a girl as profile pic than people will go easy (Like they do with the bad question which is asked here)