# how to change HTML checkbox state in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

**HTML source :**

```
'<div class="checkbox">' +
    '<label for="sn-checkbox-open-in-new-window">' +
    '<input type="checkbox" id="sn-checkbox-open-in-new-window" checked />'+
    lang.link.openInNewWindow +
    '</label>' +
'</div>';
```

The input checkout object is the following

```
var $openInNewWindow = self.$dialog.find('input[type=checkbox][id=sn-checkbox-open-in-new-window]');

var isChecked = linkInfo.isNewWindow !== undefined ?
        linkInfo.isNewWindow : context.options.linkTargetBlank;

    $openInNewWindow.prop('checked', isChecked);
```

When I do this, the checkbox does not change properly.
The box is not painted nor checked.

So

```
$openInNewWindow.on('click', function(event) {
        $openInNewWindow.val('checked').val(false);
        console.log($openInNewWindow.val('checked'));
        //$openInNewWindow.prop(':checked', !$openInNewWindow.prop(':checked'));
        //console.log($openInNewWindow.prop(':checked'));
      });
```

I changed the state when I clicked force, but it does not change.

How to change HTML checkbox state in **JavaScript**?

Comment: Duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206565/check-uncheck-checkbox-with-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check/Uncheck checkbox with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206565/check-uncheck-checkbox-with-javascript)

Comment: thank you guys.
but i want 'render change'

i try this, but not change checkbox button.

I tried to force it to change, but it does not change.

 $openInNewWindow.on('click', function(event) {
            $("#sn-checkbox-open-in-new-window").prop("checked", false);
          });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#sn-checkbox-open-in-new-window").prop("checked")` to get checkbox value

`$("#sn-checkbox-open-in-new-window").prop("checked", TRUE);` to check it

`$("#sn-checkbox-open-in-new-window").prop("checked", FALSE);` to un-check it

```js
$("#toggle-checkbox").on("click", function(e) {
 
  var nextValue = !$("#sn-checkbox-open-in-new-window").prop("checked");
  $("#sn-checkbox-open-in-new-window").prop("checked", nextValue);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggle-checkbox">Toggle</button>

<div class="checkbox">
  <label for="sn-checkbox-open-in-new-window">
    <input type="checkbox" id="sn-checkbox-open-in-new-window" checked /> lang.link.openInNewWindow
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you Sudarpo Chong!

i click checkbox button checkbox button is not clicked.
But if you click on the toggle button, it changes.
Why?

Comment: can you rephrase your question? i dont understand.

Comment: can change the status by pressing the button. The status does not change when the checkbox is clicked.

Comment: You mean from the above code snippet? It's working fine for me. I can toggle using button and also checkbox itself. I tried in Chrome and IE11.