# Uncheck checkbox on button press without resetting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a button which I want to reset three form inputs.

I've managed to clear the two text inputs (input 1 and input 2) but the checkbox won't clear.

```
<button  id="reset">reset</button>
```

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('reset').onclick= function() {
    var field= document.getElementById('textbox1');
    field.value= field.defaultValue;
    var field= document.getElementById('textbox2');
    field.value= field.defaultValue;
    var field= document.getElementById('agreecheckbox');
    field.value= field.defaultValue;
};
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check/Uncheck checkbox with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206565/check-uncheck-checkbox-with-javascript)

Comment: If the type of a button is undefined it behaves like a submit button

Comment: @Kos should probably have said I have tried $("#agreecheckbox").prop("checked", false); too

Answer (score 1):

This is the structure you need.  I added the onclick directly on the button and created a function(myFunctionName). I added a form around your button and checkbox because we are processing form data.  THen check to see if the checkbox is checked with this method.  if not it sets checked as empty.

CSS

```
function myFunctionName(){
if(document.getElementById('agreecheckbox').checked  == true){
document.getElementById('agreecheckbox').checked = '';
var field= document.getElementById('textbox1');
field.value= field.defaultValue;
var field= document.getElementById('textbox2');
field.value= field.defaultValue;
}}
```

HTML

```
<form id="formName" method="post">
<button onclick="myFunctionName();" type="button"  id="reset">reset</button>
<input type="checkbox" checked="" id="agreecheckbox">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing like this

`document.getElementById("agreecheckbox").checked = false;`

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example to reset checkbox with jquery.
This Solutions checks if the id reset has been clicked, if so removes the checked attribute from the checkbox id.

```js
$(function(){
$("#reset").click(function(){
   $("#chkbox").removeAttr('checked');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button  id="reset">reset</button>
<input id=chkbox type=checkbox checked>
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing to

```
var field= document.getElementById('agreecheckbox');
field.checked= false;
```

We are setting the checkbox property checked to false.
If you want to change it to true, you can set field.checked=true;

Answer (score -1):

```js
document.getElementById('reset').onclick= function() {
    var field= document.getElementById('agreecheckbox');
    field.checked= field.defaultValue;
};
```

```html
<input id="agreecheckbox" type="checkbox">
<button  id="reset">reset</button>
```

Comment: @gjames please check.

Comment: This code doesn't work alone where is the rest of it?

Comment: @Jonny problem was related to not able to reset checkbox value on click of reset. My solution gives  idea for it which can be used to implement complete solution.

Comment: we should explain our code to the user at stackovewrflow, this is to help people learn.  and what is field.defaultValue shouldn't it be "checked" or ""? defaultValue doesnt exist.  That is why it doesnt work.

Comment: Ok. I should have included that I agree.