# unchecking checkbox in Android Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

This script doesn't work on mobile chrome:

```js
function check() {
    document.getElementById("sh").checked = false;
}
```

Can you recommend an alternative which work on Android Chrome?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check/Uncheck checkbox with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206565/check-uncheck-checkbox-with-javascript)

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? When is the `check` function called and what result are you expecting? This is a very basic feature and I doubt it's not supported on chrome mobile. You should provide the HTML for your `sh` checkbox as well.

Comment: I’m building a ‘css hack’ menu.
I was testing six scripts. The scripts are good, they work perfectly on desktop and windows phone. On android the scripts don’t work. I don’t know why.

That’s why I was starting build a java script menu on this morning, and i’ll leave this problem.
Thanks for responds!

Answer (score 1):

I can give you alternatives that should work fine in modern desktop browsers but I have no idea about Android, so here goes...

Toggle its state...

```
sh.checked=!sh.checked;
```

Remove the atttribute...

```
sh.removeAttribute('checked');
```

Btw, you don't need to use *getElementById('')* if you know the ID, just use the ID directly.

Btw, I'm not surprised that...

```
sh.checked = false;
```

...doesn't work because the checked attribute was not really designed to be a boolean.

Had it been a boolean then assigning "checked" to it would always equate to false.

Booleans can only accept true or false.

So the Android JS engine you're using has the correct behavior IMHO..

Comment: I've given two examples above where I am operating DIRECTLY on a known ID. I only use getElementById() without the quotes for variables.

Comment: Nope, an ID exists either because it was declared on an element in HTML or created dynamically in JS. There's no need to create variables.

Comment: @connexo

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables

Comment: Ok, mea culpa. Learned something new, thank you! Just do *any* change to your answer will allow me to turn my downvote into an upvote.