# Can JS tell when a checkbox was checked or unchecked?

Tags: javascript

How can I modify the following JS to where it will tell me whether the checkbox was checked or unchecked?

```js
function toggleOption(x)
{
  if (???)
      alert("Checkbox with number " + x + " was checked");
  else
      alert("Checkbox with number " + x + " was UNchecked");
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleOption(1)">
```

To clarify I need to check if user clicking the checkbox made the checkbox checked, or unchecked.  I don't need to check or uncheck the box using JavaScript (the user will be doing that part)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check/Uncheck checkbox with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206565/check-uncheck-checkbox-with-javascript)

Comment: The user will check/uncheck the box, I need the JS to detect whether user has checked or unchecked the box.

Comment: Your onclick then should handle it, if its hitting your toggleOption method, the user has checked or unchecked the box

Answer (score 1):

input has a `checked` property that you can check to know the status of checkbox

```js
function toggleOption(x)
{
  var checked = document.querySelector("input").checked;
  if (checked)
      alert("Checkbox with number " + x + " was checked");
  else
      alert("Checkbox with number " + x + " was UNchecked");
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleOption(1)">
```

Comment: If there's an option `1` the chances are really high that there will also be an option `2` and `3` and `4` and ...

Comment: Why would you query for an input (which would most likely not be the same checkbox) inside the listener? Why not use `this`?