# JavaScript check if checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm want to change background color using checkbox, but it work only once. Mean if i click it again nothing change.

```
<body>
    <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="check();">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
</body>

<script>
    function check() {
        if (document.getElementsByTagName('input').checked) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        } else {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Comment: `getElementsByTagName('input')` returns a list, do `getElementsByTagName('input')[0]`

Comment: Try use search this answer for your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206565/check-uncheck-checkbox-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The [`Element.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) method returns a live HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name.

In this case you do not need to use `getElementsByTagName()` at all. Just pass `this` to the function so that you can refer that element in the function body like the following:

```js
function check(chk) {
  if (chk.checked) {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  } else {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="check(this);">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of `getElementsByTagName` will response a list of elements. In your case, you have to choose the first element to check the `checked`

```js
function check() {
  if (document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  } else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  }
}
check();
```

```html
<body>
    <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="check();">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
</body>
```