# Adding multiple actions to HTML anchor

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fLbvm5p7/2/)

PS - The X is usually a Font Awesome 3 bar icon. Click on it for menu drop-down.

I'm also aware the code is a mess, I'm rebuilding it now into a much cleaner version.

```
<nav>
    <label for="toggle"> <span>X</span> </label>
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox" />
<div class="mobnavtxt to-be-changed">
    <a data-scroll href="#about">ABOUT</a>
    <a data-scroll href="#services">SERVICES</a>
    <a data-scroll href="#blog1">BLOG</a>
    <a data-scroll href="#blog2">REVIEWS</a>
    <a data-scroll href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
    <span class="links">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
        </a>
        </span>
    <!-- links -->
    <span class="email"><a href="mailto: email@email.com">email@email.com</a></span>
</div>
<!-- mobnavtxt -->
</nav>
```

---

```
.mobnavtxt {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    z-index: -1;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 50PX 30px 30PX 40PX;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: .2s;
}

.mobnavtxt .links {
    margin: 15px 0;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
}

.mobnavtxt a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #222;
}

label {
    background: #fff;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]~.to-be-changed {
    top: -60vh;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~.to-be-changed {
    top: 0;
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

---

This is my mobile level menu.

Currently I need to press the X to open the menu, I choose a link which is set to scroll to position, then I need to press the X again to close the menu.

I'd like to set it up so this happens:

1. Press X to open menu
2. Select link to scroll to.
3. On select link, two actions happen: scroll to target AND menu closes.

How do I add achieve this? I'm a JS  newbie and currently only know enough to edit the plugins/pieces of code I've cut into my builds.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried something so far? + do you have a library for this project like jQuery or do you target a pure JS solution?

Comment: I'm quite lost as I don't know JS very well. I can see there are options for onclick, but I have no idea how to set that up.

A nudge in the right direction would be very appreciated.

Comment: "I have no idea how to set that up"...did you try any tutorials or find any examples? There are _hundreds_ available online which would show you, among other things, how to handle a click event. If you're just starting out, better to take a course than ask random bits of questions about small issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your JSFiddle, seems that you're stuck on point 3, meaning scroll to target and AND close the menu.

**SCROLL TO TARGET**

Good news for you, the scroll to target does not required any Javascript.
I assume you know about HTML Bookmark link

`<a href="#my-id">My link</a>` is connected to a div like `<div id="my-id">`
So the jump to section is directly handled by the browser

[W3C Sample of Bookmark link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_links_bookmark)

The scroll effect can be achieved by adding this CSS property to your page

```
body {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

**CLOSE MENU**

As the opening is ruled by a checkbox, which delegates with CSS the opening of your menu, you just need a JS that will uncheck it.
Check here for this purpose, Code is quite simple

[Check/Uncheck checkbox with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206565/check-uncheck-checkbox-with-javascript)

Comment: Scroll to target is working currently, I just didn't include it in the code.

It has JS hooked to the data-scroll which smooth scrolls to the #tag.

Thanks though!

Comment: The second part CLOSE MENU looks like a very probable solution. Will try it out and report back, TYVM!

Comment: PERFECT! Used the data from this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fjaeger/L9z9t04p/4/ to add onclick to both the burger and each individual menu link. Now it opens with the burger, and closes with the link chosen.

I think I might need to adapt it later to make it also close on burger, but for now this will do. TYVM

Comment: Figured that last part out too! Thanks so much for this, I was really struggling. :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".menu-bars").on("click", function(){
    $("nav ul").toggleClass("showing");
  });

  $("nav ul li").on("click", function(){
    $("nav ul").removeClass("showing");
  });
});
```

```css
nav ul{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ac5463;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

nav ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

nav ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #ac5480;
}

.menu-bars{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #005c48;
  text-align: right;
  box-shadow: border-box;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}

.menu-bars .fas{
  margin-right: 20px;
}

nav ul{
    max-height: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 4.5em;
  }

  nav ul li{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .menu-bars{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }

  .showing{
    max-height: 20em;
    position: fixed;
    top: 4.5em;
  }
  .section_content{
  height: 400px;
background-color: #cccccc;
padding-top: 60px;
  }
  .jquery{
  background-color: yellow;
  }
  .script{
  background-color: red;
  }
  .net{
  background-color: black;
  }
  .contact{
  background-color: grey;
  }
  .about{
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" >

<nav>
  <div class="menu-bars">
    <i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x"></i>  
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#jQuery">jQuery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#script">Script</a></li>
    <li><a href="#net">Net</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="section_content" id="home">
<h2>Home</h2>
</div>
<div class="section_content jquery" id="jQuery">
<h2>jQuery</h2>
</div>
<div class="section_content script" id="script">
<h2>Script</h2>
</div>
<div class="section_content net" id="net">
<h2>Net</h2>
</div>
<div class="section_content contact" id="contact">
<h2>Contact</h2>
</div>
<div class="section_content about" id="about">
<h2>About</h2>
</div>
```

I've solve your problem. I hope It will help you to get your goal. when you click the bar icon the menu will open and close automatically.

Comment: yes, but it's a very easy way. there is nothing complicated. :) I think @Zakalwe can understand.

Comment: As OP mentioned they are just starting out, you cannot even assume they know what jQuery is. You should at least explain your code instead of just dumping it into the question, for a _beginner_ nothing will be obvious, even the small things. And it would be better to learn vanilla JS first really. Just my opinion of course.

Comment: Yes, you are right @ADyson. I will remember it for next time. Thanks :)

Comment: you can still edit this answer and improve it, no need to give up on it and wait for next time

Comment: but there is no way to uncheck the checkbox without JS, isn't it ? I will Improve the answer but it must to use the JS.

Comment: no-one said anything about not using JS, my comment was merely about the use of jQuery. Your answer can by all means be jQuery-based, all I was saying was that you need to explain that dependency very clearly.