# refresh page and save value of checkbox on value changes

Tags: jquery

so I use the below code to refresh a page on dropdownlist value changes and save the value in local storage and load it again:

```
<select class="CB" id="CB" disabled>
   <option value="a">a</option>
   <option value="b">b</option>
</select>


<script>
    if(localStorage.getItem('CB')){
    $('#CB').val(localStorage.getItem('CB'));
    }

    $('#CB').change(function(){
    localStorage.setItem('CB',$('#CB').val() );
    location.reload();
    });
</script>
```

but the code above doesn't work for checkbox for some reasons! How can do the similar thing for a checkbox?

Comment: The value of checkbox do not change.  Their `checked` state changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check/Uncheck checkbox with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206565/check-uncheck-checkbox-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a `checkbox` instead of a `select`, you'll need to target the ["checked" property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Property/checked).

```js
var $CB = $('#CB');

if (localStorage.getItem('CB')) {
  $CB.prop('checked', localStorage.getItem('CB') == 'true');
}

$CB.on('change', function() {
  localStorage.setItem('CB', $CB.prop('checked'));
  location.reload();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="CB">
```

StackSnippets [don't provide access to `localStorage`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345385/why-are-we-disallowed-to-use-html5-local-storage-on-code-snippets), so [here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6jzbexL2/) for demonstration.