# Check a box from a loaded Javascript

Tags: javascript

We use:

```
<div id="bbox-root">
<script type="text/javascript">
       window.bboxInit = function () {
           bbox.showForm('92da1507-775e-47da-a152-5447a6b6db6c');
       };
       (function () {
           var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
           e.src = 'https://bbox.blackbaudhosting.com/webforms/bbox-min.js';
           document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(e);
       } ());
</script>
</div>
```

This loads a donation form on our website. The company that provides this doesn't allow a box to be checked by default. Is there a way to do this after the page/script loads?

You can see it live at https://givesaintagnes.org/doctorsday/

Specifically I want to have this box checked by default:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ theCheckBox.checked = true; });` Also, `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]` is a waste of processing power, just use: `document.querySelector('head')`

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded `is for the initial HTML loading. It will not works as the interesting HTML come asynchronously after. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: @samb102 I'm well aware of when `DOMContentLoaded` fires. There is no mention of asynchronous calls in the post. OP asks if there is a way to check the box after the page loads - This does that.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help. Could you specify where that line would need to go? Thanks again!

Comment: It can go in any `script` tag on your page, but you need to replace `theCheckBox` with a proper reference to the checkbox in question.

Comment: I've provided the proper reference in my answer

Comment: I've updated my answer to wait to check the checkbox until it is loaded

Comment: @JFarq Are you using jQuery? That would likely make this easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Google Chrome dev tools, I see that the id of the checkbox is `bboxdonation_tribute_chkTributeGift`. Using that id, the box can be checked after loading with:

```
document.getElementById('bboxdonation_tribute_chkTributeGift').checked = true;
```

Here is how I would recommend detecting that the checkbox has been added (modifying your original code):

```
(function() {
  var e = document.createElement('script');
  e.async = true;
  e.src = 'https://bbox.blackbaudhosting.com/webforms/bbox-min.js';
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(e);

  setTimeout(checkCheckbox, 10);

  function checkCheckbox() {
    if (document.getElementById('bboxdonation_tribute_chkTributeGift')) {
      // element found, check box
      document.getElementById('bboxdonation_tribute_chkTributeGift').checked = true;
      document.getElementById('bboxdonation_tribute_chkTributeGift').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    } else {
      // wait a little longer
      setTimeout(checkCheckbox, 10);
    }
  }

}());
```

Comment: And on what event do you decide to run it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the box with JavaScript like this:

```
document.getElementById("checkbox").checked = true;
```

If you have JQuery use `$(document).ready(function() { //code here })`to run this only when the page has loaded. If you don't have JQuery, adding the script just before closing the `<body>` tag is the safest way.

More info:

- [Check/Uncheck checkbox with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206565/check-uncheck-checkbox-with-javascript)
- [$( document ).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: How is this different than the answer I already supplied? This doesn't provide the correct id for the checkbox. The user is also not waiting for the document to load, he is waiting for the script he is dynamically including to load.

Comment: Sorry, about that, I started writing before you posted and didn't see your answer. :(