# How to check another checkbox when click first checkbox? My checkbox list retrieve from datafile

Tags: jsf

I am new in jsf. My checkbox list retrieve from datatable. if checkbox with documentId 101 selected, system should auto select another checkbox which documentId 102. How to code this problem?

```
<p:dataTable id="popup1" var="comp1" rows="10" 
   value="#{ExaBackingBean.managedBean.popupcomp1List}" 
   editable="true" 
   selection="#{ExaBackingBean.managedBean.popupcomp1Select}" 
   rowKey="#{comp1.documentId}" rowIndexVar="index"> 
  <ac:paginator for="popup1"></ac:paginator> 

<p:column style="width:3px;text-align:center;" > 
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{comp1.selected}"> 
   <p:ajax listener="#{ExaBackingBean.ckechboxSelectPairingAction(comp1.documentId)}" partialSubmit="true" process="@this" update="@([id$=CompChecklist])" /> 
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox> 
</p:column> 

// ExaBackingBean
public void ckechboxSelectPairingAction(int documentId) throws Exception { 

if (documentId == 101) { 
    System.out.println("documentId test"+documentId); 
    --- checkbox101 & checkbox102 will check
}
```

Comment: Show your BackedBean code.

Comment: at the below is from the backedbean code. // ExaBackingBean
public void ckechboxSelectPairingAction(int documentId) throws Exception {

Comment: currently System.out.println("documentId test"+documentId);  successful displayed.. 10:38:02,090 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) documentId 101 -------- but I don't know what coding to put for the  checkboxes.. I have tried many way but  failed. please help me.. tq.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you want to show many check boxes, then you should to use `selectManyCheckbox` instead of `selectBooleanCheckbox`.

Let's create pseudo example, how to choose some value depending other:

**HTML clode**

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="basic" value="#{bean.selectedItems}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableItems}" />
    <p:ajax listener="#{bean.someLogic}" update="someComponent"/>
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

---

**BackedBean**

```
private Map<String, String> availableItems; // +getter (no setter necessary)
private List<String> selectedItems; // +getter +setter

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    availableItems = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    availableItems.put("Document1 label", "document1");
    availableItems.put("Document2 label", "document2");
    availableItems.put("Document3 label", "document3");
}

public void someLogic() {
    boolean contains = selectedItems.contains("document1");
    if (contains) {
        selectedItems.add("document2");
    }
}
```

Comment: tq. how about if available item from datatable ? from my coding the selection list came from value="#{ExaBackingBean.managedBean.popupcomp1List}"

Comment: @RuzaimahSamat, this is example, you can adopt it for yourself. Instead of `availableItems` comes your data from DB.

Comment: I will try... tqvm.

Comment: @RuzaimahSamat, please, if answer was helpful, check it as right answer. thanks.

Comment: Tqvm @BSeitkazin for your helpful answer.