# How to fill some tricky forms automatically via javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox, autofill

I need to figure out how to fill automatically some forms on certain webpage (in order to automatize a lot of regular handwork of several persons) and I cannot realize it via traditional methods, which work perfectly on other pages. I have made a figure which helps me to explain the problem -- [here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ifu3.png). The HTML-code of the page is included at the end of this post (some parts of it corresponding to the elements of interest are screenshotted in the figure). The language of the page is Russian, but I inserted the needed explanations. I need to state that I am a complete noob in javascript and all I can is to use the built-in simple editor (Firefox) to run simple codes, however, that was enough until this task. Help me, please.

There are four types of form elements, and I managed to cope with the first one, of text type (case 1 in Figure). I've run the following code and voila. The analogical method worked for all text fields. I can also address the name of the desired field and it also works perfectly.

```
requestAnimationFrame(step00);
var razstart = null; 
function step00(timestamp) {
     var raz=Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"], input:not([type])')).filter(function(a) {return a.offsetHeight > '5'});  

raz[0].value = 'Пручкина Анна Артемовна';
```

As for the other cases, I have broken my brain trying to realize how to deal with them. I'm especially disappointed by case 3, which seems to look like checkbox -- and I have managed to check/unchecked them via script on other sites. However, as far as I assume, this thing here is actually not a checkbox (I've learned via alert output that its type is also text) and I have no idea how it works -- I have inserted its code -- and others' too -- and I can provide any additional information if needed.

Nothing of the following works:

```
document.getElementsByName("enf_start_staffw")[0].checked=true;
document.getElementsByName("enf_start_staffw")[0].value=1;
document.getElementsByName("enf_start_staffw")[0].click();
```

A probably important moment is that for cases 2-4 when you manually click an element/choose an option, a small indicator appears on the webpage that says "Saving". Maybe this is somehow related to the solution of the problem, however, it also appears when you finish writing the text manually in case 1, which does not hinder the work of the script.

Also, I have tried to emulate clicks on certain points of the page. It works, but it is hardly possible to make some automatization based on this so that other people will be able to use it.

Looking forward to your help!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="/favicon.ico">
 <link rel=stylesheet href='/az/lib/editing3.css' >
<link rel=stylesheet href='/az/lib/editing3-ru.css' >
<script type=text/javascript src='/az/lib/choco.js' ></script>
<script type=text/javascript src='/az/lib/editing3.js' ></script>
<script type=text/javascript src='/az/lib/d3.min.js' ></script>
<script type=text/javascript src='/az/lib/d3c.js' ></script>
<link rel=stylesheet href='/az/lib/swift.css' >
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/rnf.css"/>
 <script src="/js/rnf.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="initializeApp()"   login-error>
 <div main-container>
  <div id=sending_indicator count=0></div><div id=link_indicator></div>
   <div main-toolbar><div>
 <a open-menu href="javascript:;" onclick="openMainMenu(event)"><!--i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i--><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQAAAAEACAMAAABrrFhUAAABC1BMVEUAAAB/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI1/jI0eCun5AAAAWHRSTlMAAQIDBAUICQsMEhMXGBkcHR4fICIjJSYpKissLS44OTo7PEJDSUxNTk9QVVZbXF1eX2Ftb3h8gIKVl5iam6uvsrS8w8XHyszO0dXX2t7g4uTm6PX3+fv9du2N7gAAAi1JREFUeNrt3VdWVGEQhdFDSzAHzFlRMOdsmxHBnOXOfyQ+AIpO4ew9g/pWLxYP9ddNAAAAAAD6TJ15tPx9qPHxxc2dm8cfXfs51Hm2/c/804tDo9VTG/N/HkrNr/3+F4daB5Pkeu/8w+eJZOpncYDhQnK2ef5hOXlcHWCYzkp3gF350R3gSLrnH04KIIAAAggggAACCCCAAAIIIIAAAggggABVTuRbd4CDedUdYEfuVs//a5T91QGeJHnTHGBvkgPF8z9Nktyunf/d5NqS0P3S+T9s21gTW1htnP/51N9FwZmHdYsyS8f/XRWdmD19+WqLK+ePz9gOBgAAAAAAAAAAAGgxse/UpZ5V2XPH/luVnXlQtyz9+uim+ed/Na7LP5vcmP9e6YOJ91vX5r9R+2Tm7ZYk1e/mxkmy1Pxsbk/KH06O4+ls/ePp8ufzBxxQKA/ghogAAggggAACCCCAAAIIIIAAAggggAB1Aeo/tVX/sbXyz+3NZK56/pX2T25eTHKzeP4voySj4gWBQ0mS6a+t8y+sL0lNd/4GVuf+rMmNbhX+JXy+Y/Om5NTceKXof8JPL2/vtB0MAAAAAAAAAAAAUMJR1bZdaUdVHVV1VNVRVUdVhz3JbPXDyXFypzqAo6qOqjqqWh7ACQ0BBBBAAAEEEEAAAQQQQAABBBBAAAHqAjiq2h1gd8bdARxVdVQ1t4rnrz+qejhJ81HVC+tLUo6qOqrqqCoAAAAAABV+AwC1TqNnCfmJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" width=32></a>
 <a id=go-out href="/logout" onclick="openMainMenu(event)">ВЫХОД<!--i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i--></a>      </div></div>
  <div main-menu>
 <div main-menu-item><a id=logo-rsf href=/ ><img logo src="/res/logo-big.png"></a>
  <a id=hk href='javascript:to_x_func()'
   hotkey="Ctrl-./"
  ></a>
  <a id=sign-rsf href=/ >Российский научный фонд</a>
 </div>
 <div main-menu-item no-style></div>
  <div main-menu-item usermenu comp-style><a href="/site/user/contests">Конкурсы</a></div> <div main-menu-item usermenu quest-style><a href="/site/user/card">Анкета</a></div> <div main-menu-item usermenu req-style><a href="/site/user/bids?role=master">Заявки</a></div>   
  
  
 <div main-menu-item usermenu org-style><a href="/site/user/orgs-">Организации</a></div>  <div login-in-menu>
  </div>
   <div main-menu-item usermenu cont-style><a href="/site/anonymous/contacts">Контакты</a></div>
<!--&& !@$_REQUEST["q"] -->
 <!-- <div>is_user </div> -->
</div>
<!-- <div main-menu-item><a href="/"></a></div> -->
  <!--div main-line></div-->
  <div main-body>
   <div where-i-am="">Информационно-аналитическая система РНФ</div>
   <div main-content>
   
<head>
 <title>Информация об исполнителе</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<style> 
 label { display: block; font-weight: bold; }
 [theme='swift']>a[tag="A"]~label, [theme='swift']>[lobload]~label, [theme='swift']>input[tag]~label { font-weight: normal; }
 dfn { font-weight: normal; }
 [bool-state="yes"] a[yes], .notchanged { color:green; }
 [bool-state="no"] a[no], .changed { color:red; }
 .form-required { color: #f00; font-weight: bold; }
 [vtype="3"] { text-align: left; }  
 .btnDelete {
  float:right; 
  margin-right:1em;
  align-items: flex-start;
  text-align: center;
  color: buttontext;
  background-color: buttonface;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: outset;
  border-color: buttonface;
  border-image: initial;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
 }
 
[userstatus] td { vertical-align: top; }
 
.memberstip {
 display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-bottom: 1.5em;
    padding-top: 0em;
    padding-left: 0.9em;
    padding-right: 0.9em;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    border-radius: 5px;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 250px;
    background-color: rgb(254,252,234);
}
</style>

<h2>Информация об исполнителе проекта</h2>

<div publ auto-key=syrecordidw cmd="/az/ops/crud?table=enrf_dust6&amp;key_vals=__00000000000000001924666_~~~" locker="">



<script safe-to-copy>
 function returnToPrevPage(f, st) { 
  window.location.href='/site/user/executant-insert?rid=' + st;
 }
 
 function setAge(e, bday) {  
  var month = 0;
  var year = 0;
  if( bday != "" ) {
   var arr = bday.split('.'); 
   if(arr.length == 2) {
    month = parseInt(arr[0]); 
    year = parseInt(arr[1]);
   }
   if(year > 0) {   
    if(month > 0) {//2 as 02     
     var first_day_of_month = year + "-" + arr[0] + "-" + "01"; //1975-12-01     
     var birth = new Date(first_day_of_month);
     var report_date = "2019-06-30";//"2019-12-31";
     var now = new Date(report_date);     
     var diff = now.getFullYear() - birth.getFullYear();           
     var age = now.setFullYear(1972) < birth.setFullYear(1972) ? diff - 1 : diff;
     var v = { 'enf_agew': age.toString() };
     modificationRequest(e, v);
    }   
   }   
  }
 }
 
 function setOther(e, param, def) {
  if(e.value === '1') {
   var v;
   if(param == 'sti') {
    v = { 'enf_scientist_iw': '' 
     , 'enf_sti_state_diffw' : ''};
   }   
   if(param == 'stru') {
    v = { 'enf_scientist_ruw': '' 
     , 'enf_stru_state_diffw' : ''};    
   }   
   for(var i in v) {
    var vv = {}; vv[i] = v[i];
    modificationRequest(e, vv)
   }
   def().done(function(x) { document.reload(); });    
  }
  else
   def() 
 }
</script>


<div>
 <b>6.<span>9</span>.</b> Информация о вознаграждении<span> за счет гранта членов научного коллектива (в том числе руководителя проекта) за выполнение проекта<br></span> <i>(заполняется на каждого члена научного коллектива, указанного в приказе (приказах) 
 о формировании научного коллектива)</i><br>
</div>

<hr><a></a>
<button tag type=button class="btnDelete" del onclick="doDelete(this) && returnToPrevPage(this, '3NXu030LCBsq1sWn3_2VLb00')">Удалить</button>
<br>
<label>6.<span>9</span>.1. ФИО члена научного коллектива<span class="form-required">*</span></label> 
<span style="padding-left:2em"><dfn tag fctl name="enf_fiow" label="введите:" tip="Не может содержать цифры. Формат ввода (пример): Иванов Иван Иванович" content-resizable theme="swift" maxlength=0  required re="/^[^\d]*$/" >Пручкина Анна Артемовна</dfn></span>
<br>
<br>
<label>6.<span>9</span>.2. Месяц, год рождения<span class="form-required">*</span></label>
<span style="padding-left:2em"><dfn tag fctl name="enf_bdayw" id=bday label="введите:"
 tip="Формат ввода: ММ.ГГГГ (две цифры - месяц, четыре цифры - год, разделителем является точка). Пример: 01.1991" content-resizable vnorm="normNumberCommaToDot(this)" 
 onsave="var e = this; def().done(function(){ setAge(e, e.V()); })" theme="swift" maxlength=0  required re="/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])[.](19[1-9][0-9]|200[0-4])$/" ></dfn></span><br>
<br>
<label>6.<span>9</span>.3. Должность (при наличии трудового договора с организацией)</label>
<span style="padding-left:2em"><dfn tag fctl name="enf_appw" tip="Не может содержать цифры." label="введите:" content-resizable theme="swift" maxlength=0  re="/^[^\d]*$/" ></dfn></span>
<br>
<br>
<label>6.<span>9</span>.4. Ученая степень на дату представления отчета<span class="form-required">*</span></label>
<span style="padding-left:2em"><dfn tag=A fctl name="enf_degreew" rid="" label="выберите:" readonly theme="swift" maxlength=0  required>без ученой степени</dfn> 
 <menu mctl style='width:200px;'>
  <li><span>без ученой степени</span></li>
  <li><span>кандидат наук</span></li>   
  <li><span>доктор наук</span></li>
 </menu>
</span>
<br>
<br>
<label>6.<span>9</span>.5. Являлся на момент подписания соглашения работником организации:</label>
<span style="padding-left:2em"><dfn tag vtype=2 mkii fctl name="enf_start_staffw" tip="Поставьте галочку, если «да». Если исполнитель не являлся на момент подписания соглашения работником организации, ничего не отмечайте." theme="swift" maxlength=1  >0</dfn></span>
<br>
<br>
<label>6.<span>9</span>.6. Статус<span class="form-required">*</span></label>
<div style="padding-left:3em" class="memberstip hideLabel"><i><b>Отметьте галочками ТОЛЬКО НЕОБХОДИМОЕ и укажите, изменялся ли статус отмеченного. Возможен выбор нескольких статусов.</b></i><br> 
<b>Пример</b>: в <span>отчетном периоде</span> исполнитель-студент (месяц и год рождения: 12.1995) стал аспирантом:<br> 
отмечается статус «студент», статус изменялся: «да»;<br>
отмечается статус «аспирант», статус изменялся: «нет»;<br>
отмечается статус «без ученой степени до 30 лет (включительно)», статус изменялся: «нет»;<br>
отмечается статус «исследователь в возрасте до 39 лет (включительно)», статус изменялся: «нет».<br>
В поле «Статус «исследователь в возрасте до 39 лет (включительно)» изменился в <span>отчетном периоде</span>» выбирается ответ «нет».<br> 
<span style='color:red; font-weight:bold;'>Если в списке статусов не отмечен статус «исследователь в возрасте до 39 лет (включительно)», а также изменялся он или нет (если изменялся - обязательно укажите дату), то 
вознаграждение этого исполнителя НЕ БУДЕТ включено в автоподсчет суммы вознаграждения исполнителей до 39. Таким образом, для участников до 39 лет (включительно), чье вознаграждение нужно подсчитывать автоматически, 
статус «исследователь в возрасте до 39 лет (включительно)» отмечается дважды (в списке статусов и в поле «Статус «исследователь в возрасте до 39 лет (включительно)» изменился 
в <span>отчетном периоде</span>»).</span><br>
<b><i>У не используемых для данного члена научного коллектива статусов НЕ НАДО отмечать изменения галочками.</i></b>
<br><br>
</div> 
 
<table userstatus>  
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>студент очной формы обучения&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
   <td>cтатус изменился в <span>отчетном периоде</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>    
   <td><dfn tag vtype=2 mkii fctl name="enf_studentw" id=student tip="Поставьте галочку если исполнитель в отчетном периоде является/являлся студентом очной формы обучения." theme="swift" maxlength=1  ></dfn></td>
   <td><dfn tag vtype=3 fctl name="enf_stud_state_diffw" id=studdiff onrefresh="this.presentA('required',(I('student').V()==='1'))" tip="Нажмите «да» или «нет» (выбор будет выделен цветом). 
   Если статус «студент очной формы обучения» изменился в отчетном периоде (например, студент закончил обучение), нажмите «да». Если в отчетном периоде исполнитель остается студентом, нажмите «нет». 
   Если исполнитель не является/не являлся студентом, ничего не отмечайте." theme="swift" maxlength=1  ></dfn></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table> 
<table userstatus>  
 <tbody>   
  <tr>
   <td>аспирант (интерн, ординатор, адъюнкт) очной формы обучения&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
   <td>cтатус изменился в <span>отчетном периоде</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><dfn tag vtype=2 mkii fctl name="enf_postgraduatew" id=postgraduate tip="Поставьте галочку если исполнитель в отчетном периоде является/являлся аспирантом очной формы обучения." theme="swift" maxlength=1  ></dfn></td>
   <td><dfn tag vtype=3 fctl name="enf_pg_state_diffw" id=pgdiff onrefresh="this.presentA('required',(I('postgraduate').V()==='1'))" tip="Нажмите «да» или «нет» (выбор будет выделен цветом). 
   Если статус «аспирант (интерн, ординатор, адъюнкт) очной формы обучения» изменился в отчетном периоде (например, аспирант закончил обучение), нажмите «да». Если в отчетном периоде исполнитель остается аспирантом, 
   нажмите «нет». Если исполнитель не является/не являлся аспирантом, ничего не отмечайте." theme="swift" maxlength=1  ></dfn></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table> 
<table userstatus>  
 <tbody> 
  <tr>
   <td>член научного коллектива без ученой степени до 30 лет (включительно)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
   <td>cтатус изменился в <span>отчетном периоде</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><dfn tag vtype=2 mkii fctl name="enf_young_without_degreew" id=youngwd tip="Поставьте галочку если исполнитель в отчетном периоде является/являлся членом научного коллектива без ученой степени до 30 лет (включительно)." theme="swift" maxlength=1  ></dfn></td>
   <td><dfn tag vtype=3 fctl name="enf_ywd_state_diffw" id=ywddiff onrefresh="this.presentA('required',(I('youngwd').V()==='1'))" tip="Нажмите «да» или «нет» (выбор будет выделен цветом). 
   Если статус «без ученой степени до 30 лет (включительно)» изменился в отчетном периоде (например, исполнитель получил степень «кандидат наук» или ему исполнился 31 год), нажмите «да». Если в отчетном периоде статус не 
   изменился, нажмите «нет». Если исполнитель не является/не являлся членом научного коллектива без ученой степени до 30 лет (включительно), ничего не отмечайте." theme="swift" maxlength=1  ></dfn></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<table userstatus>  
 <tbody> 
  <tr>
   <td>кандидат наук в возрасте до 35 лет (включительно)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
   <td>cтатус изменился в <span>отчетном периоде</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><dfn tag vtype=2 mkii fctl name="enf_young_phdw" id=yphd tip="Поставьте галочку если исполнитель в отчетном периоде является/являлся кандидатом наук в возрасте до 35 лет (включительно)." theme="swift" maxlength=1  ></dfn></td>
   <td><dfn tag vtype=3 fctl name="enf_yphd_state_diffw" id=yphddiff onrefresh="this.presentA('required',(I('yphd').V()==='1'))" tip="Нажмите «да» или «нет» (выбор будет выделен цветом). 
   Если статус «кандидат наук в возрасте до 35 лет (включительно)» изменился в отчетном периоде (кандидату наук исполнилось 36 лет или он получил степень «доктор наук»), нажмите «да». Если в отчетном периоде статус не изменился, нажмите «нет». 
   Если исполнитель не является/не являлся кандидатом наук в возрасте до 35 лет (включительно), ничего не отмечайте." theme="swift" maxlength=1  ></dfn></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<table userstatus>  
 <tbody> 
  <tr>
   <td>исследователь в возрасте до 39 лет (включительно)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
   <td>cтатус изменился в <span>отчетном периоде</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><dfn tag vtype=2 mkii fctl name="enf_youngw" id=young tip="Поставьте галочку если исполнитель в отчетном периоде является/являлся исследователем в возрасте до 39 лет (включительно)." theme="swift" maxlength=1  ></dfn></td>
   <td><dfn tag vtype=3 fctl name="enf_young_state_diffw" id=youngdiff onrefresh="this.presentA('required',(I('mainstate').V()!='нет' && I('young').V()==='1'))" tip="Нажмите «да» или «нет» (выбор будет выделен цветом). 
   Если исследователю в отчетном периоде исполнилось 40 лет, нажмите «да». Если в отчетном периоде исследователь не достиг возраста 40 лет, нажмите «нет». 
   Если исполнитель не является исследователем в возрасте до 39 лет (включительно), ничего не отмечайте." theme="swift" maxlength=1  ></dfn>   </td>
  </tr>   
 </tbody>
</table>
<table userstatus>  
 <tbody> 
  <tr> 
   <td>российский <span>ученый</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
   <td>cтатус изменился в <span>отчетном периоде</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><dfn tag vtype=2 mkii fctl name="enf_scientist_ruw" id=stru tip="Поставьте галочку если исполнитель в отчетном периоде является/являлся российским ученым. НЕ СТАВЬТЕ данный статус студентам!" onsave="setOther(this, 'sti', def)" theme="swift" maxlength=1  ></dfn></td>
   <td><dfn tag vtype=3 fctl name="enf_stru_state_diffw" id=strudiff onrefresh="this.presentA('required',(I('stru').V()==='1'))" tip="Нажмите «да» или «нет» (выбор будет выделен цветом). Если исполнитель не является российским ученым, ничего не отмечайте." theme="swift" maxlength=1  ></dfn></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<table userstatus>  
 <tbody> 
  <tr>
   <td>иностранный <span>ученый</span>*&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
   <td>cтатус изменился в <span>отчетном периоде</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><dfn tag vtype=2 mkii fctl name="enf_scientist_iw" id=sti tip="Поставьте галочку если исполнитель в отчетном периоде является/являлся иностранным ученым." onsave="setOther(this, 'stru', def)" theme="swift" maxlength=1  ></dfn></td>
   <td><dfn tag vtype=3 fctl name="enf_sti_state_diffw" id=stidiff onrefresh="this.presentA('required',(I('sti').V()==='1'))" tip="Нажмите «да» или «нет» (выбор будет выделен цветом). Если исполнитель не является иностранным ученым, ничего не отмечайте." theme="swift" maxlength=1  ></dfn></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<hr>
* <span style='font-size:x-small;'>В том числе граждане Российской Федерации, не являющиеся на момент включения в состав научного коллектива налоговыми резидентами Российской Федерации.</span>
<hr>
<span>или</span><span style="padding-left:1em"><dfn tag=A fctl name="enf_statew" rid="" label="можно указать, если ни один из статусов выше не подходит:" id=f_state readonly theme="swift" maxlength=0 ></dfn> 
 <menu mctl style='width:200px;'>
  <li><span>иное</span></li>  
 </menu>
</span>
<br>
<br>
<span style='font-weight:bold;'>Статус «исследователь в возрасте до 39 лет (включительно)» изменился в <span>отчетном периоде</span>:<span class="form-required">*</span></span>
<span><dfn tag=A fctl name="enf_state_diffw" rid="" label="выберите:" id=mainstate readonly tip="Если данный статус не изменился/не имеет отношения к исполнителю, выбирайте «нет». Статус меняется, если исполнителю в отчетном периоде исполнилось 40 лет." theme="swift" maxlength=0  required></dfn> 
 <menu mctl style='width:200px;'>
  <li><span>нет</span></li>
  <li><span>да, статус сменился по возрасту</span></li>   
 </menu>
</span>
<br>
<br>
<b>Дата изменения статуса</b><dfn tag vtype=D fctl name="enf_state_datew" onrefresh="this.presentA('required',(I('mainstate').V()!='нет'))" label="укажите, если статус менялся:" tip="Cначала выберите вариант ответа в поле 
выше - «Статус «исследователь в возрасте до 39 лет (включительно)» изменился в отчетном периоде»! Дату необходимо заполнить ТОЛЬКО ЕСЛИ СТАТУС ИЗМЕНЯЛСЯ. Если статус «до 39» не менялся для данного исполнителя, но менялся 
какой-то другой статус, можете указать здесь дату смены другого статуса." theme="swift"  vmin="'2018-07-01'" vmax="'2019-06-30'" ></dfn><br>
<br>
<label>6.<span>9</span>.7. Форма отношений с организацией<span class="form-required">*</span></label>
<div class="memberstip hideLabel">Необходимо указать форму отношений с организацией.</div><br><span style="margin-left:2em">трудовой договор&nbsp;</span><dfn tag vtype=2 mkii fctl name="enf_employment_contractw" tip="Поставьте галочку, если с исполнителем заключен трудовой договор. Если нет, не отмечайте." theme="swift" maxlength=1  ></dfn><br><span style="margin-left:2em">гражданско-правовой договор&nbsp;</span><dfn tag vtype=2 mkii fctl name="enf_civil_contractw" tip="Поставьте галочку, если с исполнителем заключен гражданско-правовой договор. Если нет, не отмечайте." theme="swift" maxlength=1  ></dfn><br>
<br>
<label>6.<span>9</span>.8. Дата включения в состав научного коллектива (по приказу)<span class="form-required">*</span></label>
<span style="padding-left:2em"><dfn tag vtype=D fctl name="enf_date_begw" id=dstart label="укажите:"
tip="Дата используется для автоматического расчета показателей кадрового состава научного коллектива." theme="swift"  required re="/^(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])[.](0[1-9]|1[0-2])[.](201)(7|8|9)$/" vmin="'2017-07-01'" vmax="'2019-06-30'" ></dfn></span><br>
<br>
<label>6.<span>9</span>.9. Реквизиты документа о включении в состав научного коллектива<span class="form-required">*</span></label>
<span style="padding-left:2em"><dfn tag fctl name="enf_doc_begw" tip="Формат ввода: Приказ...№...от... (например: Приказ №123 от 09.08.2018 г.)." label="введите:" content-resizable theme="swift" maxlength=0  required ></dfn></span>
<br>
<br>
<label>6.<span>9</span>.10. Дата исключения из состава научного коллектива (при наличии)</label>
<span style="padding-left:2em"><dfn tag vtype=D fctl name="enf_date_endw" id=dend label="укажите при наличии:"
tip="Дата используется для автоматического расчета показателей кадрового состава научного коллектива." theme="swift"  re="/^(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])[.](0[1-9]|1[0-2])[.](201)(8|9)$/" vmin="'2018-07-01'" vmax="'2019-06-30'" ></dfn></span><br>
<br>
<label>6.<span>9</span>.11. Перечень дат и реквизитов иных приказов об изменении состава научного коллектива (при наличии)</label>
<pre tag fctl name="enf_dw(details)" label="введите (при наличии):" tip="Дополнительная информация (при необходимости)." style="padding-left:2em" class="t10data" wide theme="swift"   content-resizable ></pre><br>
<br>
<label>6.<span>9</span>.12. Реквизиты документа об исключении из состава научного коллектива (при наличии)</label>
<span style="padding-left:2em"><dfn tag fctl name="enf_doc_endw" tip="Формат ввода: Приказ...№...от... (например: Приказ №321 от 28.12.2018 г.)." label="введите при наличии:" content-resizable theme="swift" maxlength=0  ></dfn></span>
<br>
<br>
<label>6.<span>9</span>.13. Сумма вознаграждения с начислениями<span class="form-required">*</span><br>
(если изменялся статус (пункт 6.<span>9</span>.6.) - до изменения статуса, в том числе в месяц, когда изменился статус)</label>
<dfn tag vtype=N fctl name="enf_money1w" label="введите:" maxlength=6 vnorm="normNumberCommaToDot(this)" tip="Указывается в тыс.руб. Сумму необходимо округлить до 1 знака после запятой (если есть дробная часть). 
Пример: 302441 руб. следует вводить как 302.4 тыс.руб." theme="swift" maxlength=38  required re="/^\d+(?:[.][0-9]{1})?$/" vmin="'0'" vmax="'2000'" ></dfn><b>&nbsp;тыс. руб.</b> 
<br>
<br>
<label>6.<span>9</span>.14. Сумма вознаграждения с начислениями после изменения статуса (заполняется в случае изменений статуса)</label>
<dfn tag vtype=N fctl name="enf_money2w" label="введите в случае изменений статуса:" maxlength=6 vnorm="normNumberCommaToDot(this)" tip="Если статус изменился, необходимо внести в данное поле сумму после изменения статуса, а в поле выше - сумму до изменения. 
Если статус не менялся, укажите всю сумму в поле выше, а данное поле оставьте пустым. Указывается в тыс.руб. Сумму необходимо округлить до 1 знака после запятой (если есть дробная часть). 
Пример: 1537 руб. следует вводить как 1.5 тыс.руб." theme="swift" maxlength=38  re="/^\d+(?:[.][0-9]{1})?$/" vmin="'0'" vmax="'2000'" ></dfn><b>&nbsp;тыс. руб.</b> 
<div>
<br>
<span><i>Если информация об исполнителе не проходит проверку после исправления ошибок в полях, нажмите кнопку </i></span><button type="button" onclick="document.location.reload()">Обновить</button><span><i>, затем снова нажмите кнопку «Проверить» (ниже).</i></span><br>
<span><i>Если после однократного нажатия кнопки «Обновить» проверка всё равно не пройдена - следовательно, ошибка не была исправлена (нет смысла снова нажимать "Обновить", необходимо сначала исправить ошибку).</i></span><br>
<span><i>Если проверка информации об исполнителе не пройдена здесь, в фин. отчете проверка также не будет пройдена.</i></span>
</div><br>
<div>
 <button id="check" theme="swift" onclick="checkThisCard(this)">Проверить</button>
</div><br>
</div>   </div>
     </div>
 </div>
<div class="ym-counter"><!-- Yandex.Metrika counter -->
<script type="text/javascript">
(function (d, w, c) {
    (w[c] = w[c] || []).push(function() {
        try {
            w.yaCounter23893609 = new Ya.Metrika({id:23893609,
                    webvisor:true,
                    clickmap:true,
                    trackLinks:true,
                    accurateTrackBounce:true});
        } catch(e) { }
    });

    var n = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],
        s = d.createElement("script"),
        f = function () { n.parentNode.insertBefore(s, n); };
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.async = true;
    s.src = (d.location.protocol == "https:" ? "https:" : "http:") + "//mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js";

    if (w.opera == "[object Opera]") {
        d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", f, false);
    } else { f(); }
})(document, window, "yandex_metrika_callbacks");
</script>
<noscript><div><img src="//mc.yandex.ru/watch/23893609" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;" alt="" /></div></noscript>
<!-- /Yandex.Metrika counter --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check/Uncheck checkbox with JavaScript (jQuery or Vanilla)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206565/check-uncheck-checkbox-with-javascript-jquery-or-vanilla)

Comment: `.checked` is to check a checkbox....

Comment: @Dementic While this may be a good pointer, there is a lot in this question that is not covered by the duplicate target.

Comment: @PaulStenne i already retracted the vote when noticed it.

Comment: @Max Some of the HTML Code would be very helpful.

Comment: @Max Your question is complex and will need some work to be a good, answerable problem. Please check the [tour], and then see [ask] and **particularly** how to build a [mcve].

Comment: @Dementic -- as I mentioned, that thing is surprisingly not a checkbox

Comment: @Dementic, I've pasted the HTML-code. Also some parts of it corresponding to the elements of interest are screenshoted in the attached figure

Comment: if i had to guess, there is some async function that runs in the background and some custom validation to make the checked property.

Comment: @Dementic, thank you, but my knowledge of javascript is unfortunately not enough to understand how to make profit from this information. Or does it mean that there may be no way to automatize form filling?