# Javascript check first checkbox only

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have some code that repeat a multiple times with some checkboxes in it.

What I need is that only the first checkbox should be checked, in the example you see that all checkboxes are checked because I set so in the code, but I only need te first one to be checked.

How can I achieve that with javascript?

I've tried a couple things, but because the checkbox are inside divs I have no idea how to get this working...

[image]

Comment: Please post the raw code instead of image, also post the code you have tried so far to achieve this ?

Comment: each checkbox has a unique id, why not just use it instead

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski Damn... Never thought of that, I was looking for a difficult way... Thanks man!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check/Uncheck checkbox with JavaScript (jQuery or vanilla)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206565/check-uncheck-checkbox-with-javascript-jquery-or-vanilla)

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski Yes that was the thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't thought of the unique ID that each checkbox has.

So it's done with:

```
document.getElementById("ID_Checkbox").checked = true;
```